# frontmatter is one column body matter is 3 columns

Tags: macros, multicol

I would like `frontmatter` should be in single column (one column). After `\maketitle` contents should be in `3 columns`. How do control in LaTeX class file?

My LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{owns}
\begin{document}
\title{Book Title}
\author{Balaji, K.\/}
\maketitle
\begin{multicols}{3}
...
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Class file code is:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em
\begin{multicols}{3}  
}

\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}
```

But it's not working. How do achieve this?

Comment: Why have you got a dangling `\bgroup` at the end of your definition of `\@maketitle`?  And why do you have `\multicols` both in the macro and in the document body?

Comment: @Thruston: I have edited the questions and i have need `bodymatters` should print in 3 columns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to apply `multicols` behind the scene and not add it as an environment to the document body, then you need to ensure that it is automatically started after `\maketitle` and closed before `\end{document}`.

The use of `\AtEndDocument` the way you tried it is fine, but your placement of `\begin{multicols}{3}` inside `\@maketitle`is wrong. I don't know how the code for `\maketitle` looks in your "owns" class, but if it was modeled after the definition in the standard classes, say `book.cls` then `\@maketitle` inside is called inside a group and that then generates errors. So the correct placement for the start is at the very end of `\maketitle` and not at the end of `\@maketitle`.

As an example with the `book` class:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for the \appto cmd  

\appto\maketitle{\begin{multicols}{3}}

\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Book Title\thanks{A class using multicols}}
\author{Balaji, K.\/\thanks{And some more thanks}}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

As a result you get:

[image]

Comment: Great Frank! Working fine.

Comment: It's possible `environment` should be multicolumn. Please refer <a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113682/mixing-twocolumn-and-create-fourcolumn-reference-on-same-page">It's possible?</a>